# Swagger Annotations don't working

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm developing a REST api using Spring Boot 2. I've added the SpringFox dependencies for Swagger2 and Swagger-UI in build.gradle file, like below:

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.4.0'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.4.0'
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the swagger annotations like @EnableSwagger2 are not recognized. What should I do?

**EDIT**

Only the swagger2 dependency doesn't work. It seems that gradle don't provide it. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you check if these depencies are visible in dependency tree? Use ‘gradle dependecies’ command to check that.

Comment: I've already checked and the dependencies were recognized. But it seems that I don't have all necessary packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've find the solution. I've just replaced 2.7.0 version instead of 2.4.0 version of swagger2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not compile group, but implementation group:

```
implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.7.0'
implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.7.0'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49218079/3303074)